# Create the button press effect seen in this app-demo video, with jQuery and/or CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, button

http://youtu.be/sXqXpwyBI1k

Notice when the guy presses most of the buttons, the button quickly changes to a lighter shade of its natural color, then quickly fades back to it's normal color, and at the same time it's border animates out, like there's another element with just a border behind the button that increases in width and height and fades out.

I've been trying to create this button-press effect for awhile now and.. I kind of suck.. So I wanted to know if it could be done with jQuery and/or CSS, or if anyone has seen it done somewhere on the internet or has an example?

The effect happens when he's entering a new players name, watch on that screen.

Comment: You'll have to use the HSV color space if you want the color change to work for an arbitrary starting color. As for the animations, do some research.

Comment: @Blender Mmmmm WRONG. Thanks though kid.

Comment: What's with the attitude? My point was that controlling the V attribute of a HSV color object lets you control the lightness of a color, which isn't something you can readily do with RGB, as the lightness is a function of all three color channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] i was curious to see if i could get some kind of expanding border in css so i added that to the fiddle

Draconis's answer is good, jquery animate will work well with older browers, css transitions are however going to be smoother, so if you are targeting modern safari, firefox, and chrome they work great.  Heres a little example for an animated button (this is on hover, not click)

http://jsfiddle.net/dTqkK/2/

Of course a mix of both is probably the best answer, using something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to distinguish whether a browser can support the css transitions and falling back to javascript if it can't.

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of animation is a bit complex for css, you might need jquery animate functions for this. I would do this like, place a container div(has border like in video) with for every button with display:none and absolute position(so when we resize this other elements wont effect), when button is clicked display that container div with `.fadeIn` then animate that div's height and width to button's height and width value witdh `.animate` then `.fadeout` container div. While doing this use `.css` function for button to change it's color and a callback function change it to normal color and make container div's width and height a bit bigger than button when animation is finished.

You can do this in many ways since this is an animation, that's how i would do this.